# NUXT Duplicating Styles

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Within my NUXT project it seems that CSS is being duplicated, not only on individual components, but when compiled duplicates styles from my nuxt.config.js - styleResources -> scss into the `head` tag.

This seems to be a problem for me pre NUXT 2.0 as well as post (current ver: 2.8.1). I've tried a bunch of things on build but I must be missing something...

My config for the global styles:

```
module.exports = {
...
    styleResources: {
        scss: [
            '~/styles/variables.scss',
            '~/styles/normalize.scss',
            '~/styles/forms.scss',
            '~/styles/mixins.scss',
            '~/styles/type.scss',
            '~/styles/buttons.scss',
            '~/styles/font.scss',
            '~/styles/loader.scss'
        ],
    },
    build: {
        path: '',
        parallel: true,
        cache: true,

        optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            runtimeChunk: true,
            concatenateModules: true,
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                minSize: 30000,
                maxSize: 0,
                minChunks: 1,
                maxAsyncRequests: 20,
                maxInitialRequests: 3,
                automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
                name: true,
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendors: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        priority: -10
                    },
                    default: {
                        minChunks: 2,
                        priority: -20,
                        reuseExistingChunk: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        // extractCSS: true,
        optimizeCSS: true,
        publicPath: process.env.CDN_URL || '',
        /*
        ** Run ESLint on save
        */
        extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
            if (isDev && isClient) {
                config.module.rules.push({
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                    // loader: 'pug-plain-loader',
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/
                })
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                mapboxgl: 'mapbox-gl'
            })
        ]
    }
...
}
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/wviJ3.png
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBoRE.png

The end goal is to obviously not have duplicate styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nuxt-styleResources module is only meant to share scss variables and mixins across your components. You shouldn't specify any styles there, use css field instead:

```
  styleResources: {
      scss: [
          '~/styles/variables.scss',
          '~/styles/mixins.scss',
      ],
  },
  css: [
       '~/styles/normalize.scss',
       '~/styles/forms.scss',
       '~/styles/type.scss',
       '~/styles/buttons.scss',
       '~/styles/font.scss',
       '~/styles/loader.scss'
   ]
```